# Is there a clever way to get the previous/next item using the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a list of photos ordered by creation date, as follows:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.Char()
    image = models.Image()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

I have an arbitrary Photo object photo_x. Is there an easy way to find the previous and next photos by position in the queryset? Also, I would like to wrap around if I am at the beginning/end and have it not fail if the are only 1 or 2 photos.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're in luck! Django creates `get_next_by_foo` and `get_previous_by_foo` methods by default for `DateField` & `DateTimeField` as long as they do not have `null=True`.

For example:

```
>>> from foo.models import Request
>>> r = Request.objects.get(id=1)
>>> r.get_next_by_created()
<Request: xyz246>
```

And if you reach the end of a set it will raise a `DoesNotExist` exception, which you could easily use as a trigger to return to the beginning of the set:

```
>>> r2 = r.get_next_by_created()
>>> r2.get_next_by_created()
...
DoesNotExist: Request matching query does not exist.
```

Further reading: [Extra instance methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#extra-instance-methods)

Comment: Thanks, I knew something like that existed I just couldn't think of it.

Comment: I am happy that this was what you were looking for.  Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

get_next_by_foo and get_previous_by_foo are handy, but very limited - they don't help you if you're ordering on more than one field, or a non-date field.

I wrote [django-next-prev](https://github.com/gregplaysguitar/django-next-prev) as a more generic implementation of the same idea. In your case you could just do this, since you've set the ordering in your Meta:

```
from next_prev import next_in_order, prev_in_order
from .models import Photo

photo = Photo.objects.get(...)
next = next_in_order(photo)
prev = prev_in_order(photo)
```

If you wanted to order on some other combination of fields, just pass the queryset:

```
photos = Photo.objects.order_by('title')
photo = photos.get(...)
next = next_in_order(photo, qs=photos)
```

Comment: I installed your utility, but only from this comment I understood how it should work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

To jathanism answer, its usefull, BUT **get_next_by_FOO** and **get_previous_by_FOO** ignore milliseconds... for example it will not work for objects created in loop:

```
for i in range(100):
    Photo.objects.create(title='bla', ...)

obj = Photo.objects.first()
obj.get_previous_by_created()

DoesNotExist: Photo matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: You probably wanted to do obj.get_next_by_created(); the first item is going to have the earliest timestamp and hence will have no previous.