# Getting next and previous objects in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to get the next and previous objects of a comic book issue. Simply changing the id number or filtering through date added is not going to work because I don't add the issues sequentially.

This is how my views are setup and it WORKS for `prev_issue` and does return the previous object, but it returns the last object for `next_issue` and I do not know why.

```
def issue(request, issue_id):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, pk=issue_id)
    title = Title.objects.filter(issue=issue)
    prev_issue = Issue.objects.filter(title=title).filter(number__lt=issue.number)[0:1]
    next_issue = Issue.objects.filter(title=title).filter(number__gt=issue.number)[0:1]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information of the prev/next issues? Are you intending to link to them on a page, display them in a list, etc? Are the issue_ids sequential once filtered for each title?

Comment: just a curious question: are you using a [get_absolute_url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) attribute in your model or just redirecting to the prev_issue.issue_id into the url?

Comment: I'm using the `get_absolute_url` attribute...definitely not the issue_id because I don't sequentially add issues all the time, and that would impractical.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add an `order_by` clause to ensure it orders by `number`.

```
next_issue = Issue.objects.filter(title=title, number__gt=issue.number).order_by('number').first()
```

Comment: You should do this to the prev_issue query too.  Happy to help!

Comment: I wonder how many records such a command would retrieve from the database. Just one record or all records that satisfy the filtering conditions (and we just pick one of them)? If it is the latter case, how can we make it more efficient?

Comment: The slicing syntax ([0:1]) will use "limit" queries if supported by the DB - so it should be fine on MySQL. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: Make sure the 'number' field has an index.

Comment: You don't need to use filter twice, you can do `filter(title=title, number__gt=issue.number)`

Comment: Also, this won't work as expected if one must use potentially equal fields, such as same date or number (with `__gte` and `__lte` conditions).

Comment: I would say it would have been better with `.order_by('number').first()`

Answer (score 36):

I know this is a bit late, but for anyone else, django does have a nicer way to do this, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO

So the answer here would be something something like

```
next_issue = Issue.get_next_by_number(issue, title=title)
```

Django managers to do that with a bit of meta class cleaverness.

Comment: Note that this only works for non-null DateField and DateTimeField.

Comment: I assume it's done on Django core level beacuse of the difficulties that developer could experience due to possible Date or DateTime equalness. Conditions change to `__gte` and `__lte`, which causes additional complexity to resulting query. This built-in are the best choice when dealing with previous and next objects by `Date*` fields.

Comment: Coolest solution. Thumbs up (y)

Comment: Updated link since the original is broken: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931008/is-there-a-clever-way-to-get-the-previous-next-item-using-the-django-orm

Answer (score 8):

If it's required to find **next** and **previous** objects ordered by field values that **can be equal** and those fields are not of `Date*` type, the query gets slightly complex, because:

- ordering on objects with same values limiting by `[:1]` will always produce same result for several objects;
- object can itself be included in resulting set.

Here's are querysets that also take into account the primary keys to produce a correct result (assuming that `number` parameter from OP is not unique and omitting the `title` parameter as it's irrelevant for the example):

**Previous:**

```
prev_issue = (Issue.objects
    .filter(number__lte=issue.number, id__lt=instance.id)
    .exclude(id=issue.id)
    .order_by('-number', '-id')
    .first())
```

**Next:**

```
next_issue = (Issue.objects
    .filter(number__gte=issue.number, id__gt=instance.id)
    .exclude(id=issue.id)
    .order_by('number', 'id')
    .first())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial, reduce
from django.db import models


def next_or_prev_instance(instance, qs=None, prev=False, loop=False):

    if not qs:
        qs = instance.__class__.objects.all()

    if prev:
        qs = qs.reverse()
        lookup = 'lt'
    else:
        lookup = 'gt'

    q_list = []
    prev_fields = []

    if qs.query.extra_order_by:
        ordering = qs.query.extra_order_by
    elif qs.query.order_by:
        ordering = qs.query.order_by
    elif qs.query.get_meta().ordering:
        ordering = qs.query.get_meta().ordering
    else:
        ordering = []

    ordering = list(ordering)

    if 'pk' not in ordering and '-pk' not in ordering:
        ordering.append('pk')
        qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)

    for field in ordering:
        if field[0] == '-':
            this_lookup = (lookup == 'gt' and 'lt' or 'gt')
            field = field[1:]
        else:
            this_lookup = lookup
        q_kwargs = dict([(f, get_model_attr(instance, f))
                         for f in prev_fields])
        key = "%s__%s" % (field, this_lookup)
        q_kwargs[key] = get_model_attr(instance, field)
        q_list.append(models.Q(**q_kwargs))
        prev_fields.append(field)
    try:
        return qs.filter(reduce(models.Q.__or__, q_list))[0]
    except IndexError:
        length = qs.count()
        if loop and length > 1:
            return qs[0]
    return None


next_instance = partial(next_or_prev_instance, prev=False)
prev_instance = partial(next_or_prev_instance, prev=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> note that do not use `object.get(pk=object.pk + 1)` these sorts of things, **IntegrityError** occurs if object at that pk is deleted, hence always use a query set

for visitors:

```py
''' Useage '''
"""
    # Declare our item
    store = Store.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # Define our models
    stores = Store.objects.all()
    # Ask for the next item
    new_store = get_next_or_prev(stores, store, 'next')
    # If there is a next item
    if new_store:
        # Replace our item with the next one
        store = new_store
"""

''' Function '''
def get_next_or_prev(models, item, direction):
    '''
    Returns the next or previous item of
    a query-set for 'item'.

    'models' is a query-set containing all
    items of which 'item' is a part of.

    direction is 'next' or 'prev'
    
    '''

    getit = False
    if direction == 'prev':
        models = models.reverse()
    for m in models:
        if getit:
            return m
        if item == m:
            getit = True
    if getit:
        # This would happen when the last
        # item made getit True
        return models[0]
    return False
```

[original author](https://gist.github.com/kvnn/2303613)

##### Usage

```py
# you MUST call order by to pass in an order, otherwise QuerySet.reverse will not work
qs = Model.objects.all().order_by('pk')
q = qs[0]
prev = get_next_or_prev(qs, q, 'prev')
next = get_next_or_prev(qs, q, 'next')
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
next_post = Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=self.object.date, published=True).exclude(id=self.object.id).order_by('-date').first()
next_post = next_post if next_post else Blog.objects.filter(published=True).first()
previous_post = Blog.objects.filter(date__gte=self.object.date, published=True).exclude(id=self.object.id).order_by('date').first()
previous_post = previous_post if previous_post else Blog.objects.filter(published=True).last()
```

Answer (score -3):

next_obj_id = int(current_obj_id) + 1
next_obj = Model.objects.filter(id=next_obj_id).first()

prev_obj_id= int(current_obj_id) - 1
prev_obj = Model.objects.filter(id=prev_obj_id).first()

#You have nothing to loose here... This works for me

Comment: The variable `current_obj_id` does not exist in the OP's code.

Comment: This also assumes your `id`'s are sequential, which doesn't need to be true from when results come from a `filter` query.