# Get a queryset's current order_by ordering

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'd like to find adjacent items in a queryset given a primary key, as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32102245/1888983). However I want this to work for any given queryset, that i haven't set the ordering for myself. How can I find the current ordering of a queryset for `__gt` and `__lt` filtering?

For example:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('some_field')
next_obj = get_next(queryset, after_pk, 10)
...
def get_next(queryset, pk, n):
    #ordering is unknown here
    obj = queryset.get(pk=pk)
    field = queryset.get_order_by_field_name() #???
    return queryset.filter(**{field+'__gt': getattr(obj, field)})[:n]
```

The model may define a default [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) and I can check if the queryset is [ordered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered), but I don't think either are helpful in this case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can retrieve the list of columns from order_by clause by accessing `queryset.query.order_by` property.

From django docs:

> The query attribute is an opaque object. It represents the internals of the query construction and is not part of the public API. However, it is safe (and fully supported) to pickle and unpickle the attribute’s contents as described here.

Comment: `order_by` seems to be an array, although afaik subsequent `.order_by()` calls overwrite previous ones, so I guess the value I want is always `queryset.query.order_by[-1]`?

Comment: Why not `query.order_by[0]`? If you call `.order_by()` with only one column, obviously, these values are equal, but if you're ordering by multiple cols, then the first column is the most principal (I think).

Comment: For clarity, queryset.query.order_by returns the ordering given by .order_by(...) . However, it will tell you nothing about ordering as defined in your models' Meta. So, if queryset.query.order_by turns out to be [], your models will still be ordered according to your model's Meta definition.