# Django Rest Framework - Return row and its adjacent rows on GET

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I would like to return a given row and the row before and after it (sorted by file_created_time desc) when calling GET with a uid parameter representing the row.

URL ex: `https://<domain>/api/videos/cbf02e8c-b2f5-4cd8-b3ec-87417eae2f7d?with_adjacent=true`

```
        {
            "uid": "fd5d5936-8183-495f-9a9d-8ffca25a9bab",
            "is_thumbnail": true,
            "file_name": "2018-02-03_05-00-40.jpg",
            "file_path": "thumbnails/2018-02-03_05-00-40.jpg",
            "file_created_time": "2018-02-03T05:00:40-07:00",
            "owner": "system_user",
            "created_time": "2018-02-04T14:49:29.355156-07:00"
        },
        {
            "uid": "cbf02e8c-b2f5-4cd8-b3ec-87417eae2f7d",
            "is_thumbnail": true,
            "file_name": "2018-02-03_01-09-30.jpg",
            "file_path": "thumbnails/2018-02-03_01-09-30.jpg",
            "file_created_time": "2018-02-03T01:09:30-07:00",
            "owner": "system_user",
            "created_time": "2018-02-04T14:49:30.464810-07:00"
        },
        {
            "uid": "ed626576-cc9d-4434-9f44-93a4f8f525ad",
            "is_thumbnail": true,
            "file_name": "2018-02-03_00-59-15.jpg",
            "file_path": "thumbnails/2018-02-03_00-59-15.jpg",
            "file_created_time": "2018-02-03T00:59:15-07:00",
            "owner": "system_user",
            "created_time": "2018-02-04T14:49:32.611105-07:00"
        }
```

Given the model:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    """This class represents the Videos model."""
    uid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    file_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    file_path = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    file_created_time = models.DateTimeField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                              related_name='videos',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.file_name)
```

And View:

```
class DetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """This class handles the http GET, PUT and DELETE requests."""

    queryset = Videos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
    lookup_field = 'uid'
```

I'm happy the adjust the view as necessary, that's just what I have now.

Edit:
To further complicate this, this model contains rows where is_thumbnail is either true or false. Thus, assuming I change my pk to an id, if I want to select an is_thumbnail = True row sorted by file_created_time, there's no guarantee that its adjacent rows are pk +/- 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from my other answer, I found a better way (think so) to achieve the result.I'm only adding the key part of the snippet

```
    ....
    vid_1 = Videos.objects.get(uid=input_uid)
    vid_2 = vid_1.get_next_by_file_created_time()
    vid_3 = vid_1.get_previous_by_file_created_time()
    queryset = [vid_1, vid_2, vid_3]
return Response(VideosSerializer(queryset,many=True).data)
```

We could get these kinds of things only if `DateTime` field is not null.
for more, refer this [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO) and [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441689/8283848)

Comment: Glad to know that :)