# How to pass both ListView and DetailView as parameters in views.py/urls.py?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I want to show `NEXT POST` and `PREVIOUS POST` titles under the current article as shown below :

[image]

Until now I had been passing DetailView object from `urls.py` as :

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Post, template_name = 'blog/post.html')),
```

In `post.html`, I am using post object to get the title and the body of the post.

```
<h2> {{post.title}} </h2>
<p> {{post.body|safe|linebreaks}} </p>
```

But then I realised I cannot get the list of posts to display it. So I modified `urls.py` to redirect to `views.py` which included

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.post_details)
```

**views.py**

```
post_details (request,pk):
return render(request, 'blog/post.html',{'message' : [Post.objects.all(),DetailView.as_view(model = Post)]})
```

Now when I tried using the dictionary in `post.html`, I am not getting any output.

How do I pass both DetailView and ListView as parameters to `post.html` and how do I extract it?

---

---

**SOLVED**

[Is there a clever way to get the previous/next item using the Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931008/is-there-a-clever-way-to-get-the-previous-next-item-using-the-django-orm)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to, the next and previous are both things you can pass through as extra context for which there is a [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method on all Generic Views

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context['next_post'] = my_next_post
     context['prev_post'] = my_prev_post
     return context
```

You'll then be able to use `next_post` and `prev_post` in your template.

See [Getting next and previous objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6021694/1324033) for at least one way of retrieving the next and previous posts.

Comment: I am a beginner, so this looked a bit complicated for me. Instead, I used the `pk` that was passed in `urls.py` and then got the object in `views.py` using `context = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)`. Found the previous and next post by decrementing and incrementing the pk. Then later, passed all of it to template using render. Does this sound complex?

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to write your own view for that. You're searching for pagination and django offers a good functionality for that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/).

Comment: I think that's for the current post spread over multiple pages. The previous/next links are for the current post (next/previous pages) and not for the next/previous posts.

Comment: I have edited the question details, now includes a picture. I want to show the next and previous post titles.

Comment: Ah okay... Then you're good with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021694/getting-next-and-previous-objects-in-django

Comment: Thanks for the link !